# Java - How can I use Arabic characters?

Tags: java, unicode, special-characters, arabic

I'm creating a flashcard-type game to help in learning a new language. Now the actual language I'm trying to use in my program is Urdu, but when I look at a unicode chart Arabic and Urdu letters are mixed together and I thought more people would know what I'm talking about if I said Arabic.

So, on my Windows 8 machine I can change the keyboard layout to Urdu and whatever I type into Java is correctly displayed back to me. However transferring this code to another computer with Windows 7 (at my school) changes the Urdu characters in the raw Java file to odd-characters/mumbo-jumbo. Coping and pasting the character from the online unicode chart displays in the java file, but is shown as a '?' in the actual program itself, and in the System.out method.

Now when I use the unicode escape commands (ex. \uXXXX) these are displayed correctly on both computers.

The problem is that I don't want to use escape commands every time I want to write something in Urdu. I plan on writing long sentences and many words. So I was thinking of making an array of the unicode codes and then perhaps a method that converts a English string of letters into Urdu using this array but I thought there must be an easier way to fix this problem.

I'm still kinda a beginner, but I wasn't planning on making a very complex program anyway. For any help, thanks.

Comment: So you want some way easier than the method idea? I don't quite get what you're saying

Comment: yes, and possibly just a way to type the urdu characters directly into the IDE.

Comment: I am not sure how well your IDE can handle unicode. Could you separate your Urdu from your code? You could write the Urdu in another editor. Apps that support multiple languages often separate the language from the code so they can easily be interchanged by loading a different language file.

Comment: I made a seperate Java file containing only a list of all the Arabic letters using unicode ("\u0649","\u0621"...) and was thinking of just assigning each one a value like a letter. That was for example I could make my program convert a string like "afRo" to something like "مںبد" using a method I make. But I wanted to know if there was an easier way, because when I use the Windows+Space key to change my keyboard to Urdu. The program works fine until I took it to use on a different computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a problem with the encoding in your compiler on the Windows 7 computer. You should make sure that both computers are using encoding that supports arabic/urdu characters, such as UTF-8, when compiling.

If this is not specified, the compiler will use the system's default encoding which might not support arabic/urdu characters. See [this](http://javarevisited.blogspot.no/2012/01/get-set-default-character-encoding.html) link for information on how to find/set encoding properties.

You can get the encoding currently used for compiling by adding this piece of code:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("file.encoding"));
```

Comment: I kind of understand. I tried reading what you linked. So since using the Urdu keyboard works well on the Windows 8 machine. I should see what encoding this computer is using, then add a line in my program that states it must use that encoding. Would this make it display correctly on the other computer?

I type the Urdu directly into my IDE (Netbeans) and it shows up correctly in my code. But then when I save this Java file and open it on JCreator on that Windows 7 machine, the characters change.

Comment: Yes, basically. However the compiler decides the encoding before main is run, so the best way would be to specify encoding before running the program either changing it in the IDE(if possible) or by passing it upon execution of the program through the -encoding parameter. Also, changing the default encoding for your OS could be a possibility if neither of the above works. (Updated answer with way to get current encoding.)